# Connecting to password protected DB VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi im pretty new to VBA and im trying to build a connection with a database protected by a password. This is my code.

```
Sub CostEntry()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "SAP Sheet"

     sConnString = "SourceType:=0, Source:=ODBC;DSN=SAPDATA32;Description=DATA;UID=shareuser;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=AT;DATABASE=DATA"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
        conn.Open sConnString
        Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT MBEW.BWKEY, MBEW.STPRS, MBEW.MATNR" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM SAPDATA.dbo.MBEW MBEW" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (MBEW.BWKEY='1010')")

    ' Check we have data.
        If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SAP Sheet").range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
            rs.Close
        Else
            MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
        End If

    ' Clean up
        If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Most of it i also copied from the internet adn i also think it was from stackoverflow. I alwas get the error message "Run-time error '-2147467259 (8000400)': Could not find installable ISAM". I trie inserting the line `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`
but it just gave me another error message.
Thnak you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing single quotes for the property value

```
Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
```

Comment: i added it like this      sConnString = "SourceType:=0, Source:=ODBC;DSN=SAPDATA32;Description=SAPDATA32;UID=shareuser;Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Jet OLEDB:Database Password=asdf;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=AT000616;DATABASE=SAPDATA"
but still shows me the error message "Run-time error '-2147467259 (8000400)': Could not find installable ISAM"

Answer (score 0):

Found out i just needed to add a PW:1234 field